# State the equation of the line with $x$-intercept $x=5$ and $y$-intercept $y=-2$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I really don't know how to even state the equation. I only know how to find out the $x$ and $y$ intercepts when I know the equation of the line.

However, the options are:

- a. $ 2x - 5y + 10 = 0$
- b. $-2x + 5y + 10 = 0$
- c. $-5x + 2y + 10 = 0$
- d. $ 5x - 2y + 10 = 0$

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ intercept is $a,$ the line passes through $(a,0)$

and $y$ intercept is $b,$ the line passes through $(0,b)$

Hence the equation of the line is $$\frac{y-0}{x-a}=\frac{0-b}{a-0}\iff bx+ay-ab=0$$

Comment: So what would be the correct option to this question?

Comment: @sentrl, can you see $a=5,b=-2??$

Comment: So 'b' is the correct option. Thanks :)

Comment: You won't learn if you make others solve it for you.

Comment: another "HINT"?